# Display image results in another window using QT console

Tags: ipython, spyder

Currently I am working on an image-processing project in which I manipulate images inside my code using Spyder on windows and Display the changes that occur. As of now,my Images are getting displayed on the QT console (IPython Console) itself.
The code used to display images:

```
fig = plt.figure("Image")
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_title("Watermark Image")
ax.imshow(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(watermark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I found that to display images on new window, we need to go into `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Select Backend as AUtomatic Instead of Inline` I did the same but got no output. But then in the command line I wrote `%matplotlib qt` and now the images are getting displayed in new windows but when I open that image, it shows none and does not responds. I need to force close the image and run the code again.

How can I sort this out? I am new to python.